# Installing 2 pull 30 amp breaker on 30 amp panel

Tags: dryer, washer

Am I able to run a 2 pull 30 amp breaker on a 30 amp panel for a washer and dryer? It seems the whole house is running on 30 amp main breaker

Comment: It's not a double pull, it's a double **pole**  - unless you're in Boston, but it's still written "pole" :)

Comment: Is the house part of a service shared among several residence units?  *Are you sure it has 240V service?*

Comment: Can you post photos of all panels involved please?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Your main being a 30??? I thought 60 was the minimum back when I started in the 70’s , you must have gas everything else. But more info is needed.